# Java LinkedList NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception, linked-list

I have the following method that evaluates the cost of a VRP route, but it throws a java.util.NoSuchElementException.

At first I thought the problem was in the first Iteration, where the iterator.next() is null and that's why I added the boolean firstIteration, but the problem remains!

```
private void evaluateRouteCost () {

    ListIterator<VRPNode> iterator = this.routeList.listIterator();

    boolean firstIteration=true;

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        if (firstIteration) {
            firstIteration=false;
        }

        else {
            this.routeCost += vrp.distance(iterator.previous(), iterator.next()); 
        }

    }
```

Note that routeList is a LinkedList.

Comment: You could also add some `System.out.println()`s to let you see what's going on. You would easy find out witch element is causing the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `firstIteration` is true, you still need to call `iterator.next()` (otherwise you'll still be on the first element in your second iteration).

I would however write it slightly differently:

```
ListIterator<VRPNode> iterator = this.routeList.listIterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    VRPNode current = iterator.next();

    if (iterator.hasPrevious())
        this.routeCost += vrp.distance(iterator.previous(), current); 

}
```

Comment: You have to add another iterator.next() before the loop terminate

Answer (score 0):

You're calling .previous on the first node.  Also: you can simplify this to:

```
private void evaluateRouteCost () {

    ListIterator<VRPNode> iterator = this.routeList.listIterator();

    boolean firstIteration=true;

    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
      iterator.next();
    }    

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        this.routeCost += vrp.distance(iterator.previous(), iterator.next()); 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this simple way:

```
public void evaluateRouteCost () { //http://bit.ly/t76G1Z

    ListIterator<VRPNode> iterator = this.routeList.listIterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {

        int currentId, nextId;

        currentId=iterator.next().getId();

        try {
            nextId=iterator.next().getId();
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            // when reaches the last element
            break;
        }

        this.routeCost += vrp.distance(currentId, nextId);

        iterator.previous();    
    }

}
```